Simulation Based Proof: Encryption scheme example
I was reading the book “Introduction to Modern Cryptography”, 2nd edition by Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell. Page 67 of the book gives a scheme (Construction 3.17) similar to One-Time Pad, but with a pseudorandom generator. The book goes on to demonstrate the security of the scheme by the eavsdropper experiment (forgive me if I'm wrong, but I believe it's the same principle as game-based proofs), showing that the ciphertext is indistinguishable from uniform.
CONSTRUCTION 3.17
Let G be a pseudorandom generator with expansion factor l. Define a private-key encryption scheme for messages of length l as follows:
• Gen: on input 1^n, choose uniform k ∈ {0, 1}^n and output it as the key.
• Enc: on input a key k ∈ {0, 1}^n and a message m ∈ {0, 1}^{l(n)}, output the ciphertext c := G(k) ⊕ m.
• Dec: on input a key k ∈ {0, 1}^n and a ciphertext c ∈ {0, 1}^{l(n)}, output the message m := G(k) ⊕ c.
Recently, I've been trying to learn how to do simulation-based proofs through “A Tutorial on the Simulation Proof Technique” by Yehuda Lindell and I was mainly interested in the idea of running some “encrypted garbage” (like messages with only zeros as he presents on page 5). But, I'm having a hard time understanding what the function of the simulator is and what the difference is between the game-based and simulation-based techniques.
So, I was thinking of a way to demonstrate the same 3.17 construction using the simulation technique, but I don't know how the simulator should behave in the demonstration. Does anyone have any tips that could help? Or any example that is simpler to understand than this attempt?

The philosophy behind simulation-based definitions is:

The adversary sees some stuff that was computed using some private information $X$. But this stuff doesn't leak anything about $X$ beyond the partial information $f(X)$, because there is a way to simulate all that stuff given only $f(X)$.

In the context of encryption, we could write:

The adversary sees a ciphertext that was computed using the plaintext $M$. But the ciphertext doesn't leak anything about $M$ beyond its length $|M|$, because there is a way to simulate the ciphertext given just $|M|$.

This is a reasonable way to think about security for encryption.
If we were to formalize this idea into a true simulation-based security definition, it would go something like this:

Definition: $\Sigma$ is a secure encryption scheme if there exists a simulator algorithm $\textsf{Sim}$ such that the following two games are indistinguishable:

"Real" game: A key $K$ is chosen uniformly and the adversary is given access to the oracle $\textsf{Enc}(K,\cdot)$.
"Ideal" game: The adversary is given access to an oracle $S$, where $S(M) = \textsf{Sim}(|M|)$.


You can see that in the ideal world, the oracle computes its output using only $|M|$. Thus, oracle responses in that world can leak no more than $|M|$.
Why don't we usually write security definitions for encryption in this way? Because encryption is simple enough that the strategy for $\textsf{Sim}$ is, without loss of generality, the same for every encryption scheme.
If an encryption scheme is secure, then it is always secure with respect to the simulation algorithm $\textsf{Sim}(\ell) = \textsf{Enc}(K,0^\ell)$. (I am assuming $\textsf{Sim}$ is stateful and internally chooses a $K$.)
When we simplify/specialize the simulation-based definition for this particular simulation strategy, we get the following, which looks closer to a typical game-based definition:

Definition: $\Sigma$ is a secure encryption scheme if the following two games are indistinguishable:

"Real" game: A key $K$ is chosen uniformly and the adversary is given access to the oracle $\textsf{Enc}(K,\cdot)$.
"Ideal" game: A key $K$ is chosen uniformly and the adversary is given access to the oracle $\textsf{Enc}(K, 0^{|\cdot|})$.


So, for the case of encryption, it is simply overkill to consider different encryption schemes having different simulators.
I always understand game-based security definitions as simulation-based definitions that prescribe a specific simulation strategy.
As another example, we could define security of encryption in a real-vs-random style:

Definition: $\Sigma$ is a secure encryption scheme if the following two games are indistinguishable:

"Real" game: A key $K$ is chosen uniformly and the adversary is given access to the oracle $\textsf{Enc}(K,\cdot)$.
"Ideal" game: A key $K$ is chosen uniformly and the adversary is given access to the oracle, that on input $M$ returns a uniformly sampled string of length $|M|+\lambda$ bits.


This is a simulation-based definition where we insist that the simulator runs a particular strategy -- but importantly, using only the length $|M|$ in its strategy, so leaking no more than $|M|$.
In the world beyond encryption, and especially when the cryptographic primitive involves interaction, it is no longer the case that we have a "universal" simulation strategy that we can hard-code into the security definition. It becomes necessary to let different schemes be simulated in different ways, leading to standard simulation-based security definitions ("the scheme is secure if there exists a simulator such that ...").

Thank you very much @Mikero, I really appreciate your answer. Now it's extremely clear, especially the direct connection with semantic security. And now I understand why it's not common to use this technique to demonstrate such schemes. Thank you :)
